# Does yahoo oauth api does not work on the subdomain

Tags: subdomain, authentication, yahoo-api

I am trying to implement yahoo auth api. But I am getting 401 error ie consumer_key_rejected. I use the correct consumer_key and secrete. My subdomain ie http://fbapps.jambura.com/ has been verified. Still I am getting 401 error. Here is the link http://fbapps.jambura.com/test.php. My code http://pastebin.com/VAksvt17

I dont see any OAuth applications category. http://fbapps.jambura.com/Screen%20shot%202012-03-06%20at%209.06.18%20PM.png http://fbapps.jambura.com/Screen%20shot%202012-03-06%20at%209.06.27%20PM.png

I created new project/app. used the info - but it does not work. http://fbapps.jambura.com/yahoo-401.zip here are the images. Please see if I am making any mistake. One thing though - i gave wrong consumer key it showed the same 401 error.

Comment: Turns out subdomain doesnot work.

Answer (score 0):

That's correct - the Yahoo auth flow will not automatically work for subdomains of the original application domain. It does support subdomains if you create the API key for that particular domain. For example, create a key for app domain `code.example.com`, then calls redirecting to `code.example.com` will work, but not to `example.com` or `www.example.com`.

Comment: I created another project with yahoo subdomain. This is the Information
`Consumer Key:dj0yJmk9eEx5WlFyRWx5ZFdRJmQ9WVdrOU1XRktURFp3Tm1zbWNHbzlNVEk1TmpZM09UUTJNZy0tJnM9Y29uc3VtZXJzZWNyZXQmeD1hMg--

Consumer Secret:8c63c2fa98c2e5d6a33928f4e6aed4b2f6899896

Application URL:http://fbapps.jambura.com

App Domain:fbapps.jambura.com`
But i am getting " Failed to create request token: consumer_key_rejected" error. Any idea why?